# compiler error when using throws

Tags: java

Following a simple example I found here on this site I have the example code

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Main throws AWTException{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(50, 50);  
}
}
```

when I compile this I get the error

```
Main.java:2: error: '{' expected
public class Main throws AWTException {
                 ^
1 error
```

Can someone explain what is wrong?  I have tried many different things and to me it appears as if the "throws" word is simply not recognized by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw exception in class level, it can be done in method level as:

1)`throw` in the method body, try-catch block to wrap specific statements that might throw exception.

```
    public class Test{
        public Test(){

        }

        public void testMethod(){
            try{
                //statements might throw exception
            }catch(Exception e){
                //must print the exception message here, it's a good habit...
            }
        }
    }
```

2)`throws` in the method declaration, it will propagate the exception to the method that invokes `testMethod()`, really help for further track the exception.

```
    public class Test{
        public Test(){

        }

        public void testMethod() throws Exception{
            //code goes here
        }
    }
```

3) `throws` in the class constructor declaration.

```
public class Test{
    public Test() throws Exception{

    }
}
```

In your case:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws AWTException {
        Robot bot = new Robot();
        bot.mouseMove(50, 50);  
    }
}
```

or in your static main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Robot bot = new Robot(); // if Robot constructor declared AWTException
                             // the class instance initialization line should
                             // be wrapped in the try-catch block as well
    try{
        bot.mouseMove(50, 50);//mouseMove might throw AWTException
    }catch( AWTException awte){
        System.err.println("Exception thrown:" + awte.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Strange that the example code given on this website was upgraded - multiple times.  I would be eternally grateful if you could give a code snippet that would correctly create a Robot that could be used outside a try statement.

Comment: The second method does not work.  I am new to java so I am not sure if this depends on what system/compiler you work with.  It only works if bot declaration is inside the try statement.

Comment: @user3799584 I didnt test it by myself, only point a way to solve it, you can wrap both lines into the try-catch statement, then it will be the same as `throws AWTException` after the method declaration.

Comment: @user3799584 it might because the Robot constructor declared AWTException like `public Robot throws AWTException{...}`